# how to sync in unity3d?

Tags: synchronization, unity-game-engine

I learn that in Unity3d there is no explicit sync lock (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/284228/how-to-synchronize-in-unity.html#answer-284522) but in my game I need to do this.

Both agents (pilot A & pilot B) need to modify the speed of an airplane. The pseudo-code is:

```
if (speed < threshold)
   speed += 1
```

If there is no lock, and the current speed:  speed = threshold-1.  When pilot A checks and see speed < threshold, he increments it. When he's doing it, pilot B checks, he also sees speed < threshold, he increments it again. So speed may go wild, incremented twice and ending up >= threshold.
The airplane will crash.

I know it's just a plain old example of sync, surprised that Unity doesn't support this. What is the workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/146372/are-update-and-fixedupdate-called-in-different-thr.html

You are concerned about thread concurrency where none exists.  Unity3D Update() calls are not multithreaded.  The link you include says that Unity3D doesn't guarantee script order, that's true.  But all that means is that Unity doesn't guarantee if A comes before B.  2 scripts can't update the same value at the same time.